# Is the Spanish word for "film" really the same word as for "movie"?

Tags: traducción

I'm simultaneously reading "The Grapes of Wrath" in English and Spanish ("Las Uvas de la Ira").

I came acorss this translation for "film of dust":

"pelicula de polvo."

Is this accurate? I know that "film" can mean "movie" in English, but is it also true of Spanish?

Comment: film of dust is pretty meaningless like that on its own. Why don't you post the whole sentence, huh?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is. It means both movie and coating.

- Vamos a ver una película - Let's watch a movie.

Comment: a film of dust is probably una pélicula de polvo que cubre algo...

Answer (score 10):

The phrase which you are looking for, "film of dust," can use both "película" AND "capa," the latter being the better choice.  It refers to a light coating of dust on something (remember that *The Grapes of Wrath* is set during the Dust Bowl).

Thus, one rendering in Spanish of "film of dust" would be "una capa de polvo."
*Todo estaba cubierto por una ligera capa de polvo.*

Remember to consider the context of the word/phrase, then cross-reference your rendition in the other language to be sure.

Comment: That's the reason for my question - it didn't seem to make sense to me. I know exactly what the original sentence means (I know what a film of dust is; my maternal grandparents lived in the Dust Bowl area and era). My question is, is that a correct translation? Is "pelicula" really a valid translation of the word "film" in this case? Your example ("una capa de polvo") makes a lot more sense.

Comment: `Película` is also a correct translation for `coating` read def 1 y 2 http://lema.rae.es/drae/?val=pelicula, in this case the most used is `capa` but `pelicula` is perfectly a valid choice.

Comment: Thank you, Emilio.  I fell for my own trap and did not cross-reference and have edited my previous posting.  Yes, "capa" is the best choice in this case.
Would "película" more often be used with regard to a "liquid film," such as a "film of oil on the surface"? Una película de aceite sobre la superficie.

Comment: película también es muy usada para referirse a metales, pero ya el uso depende más de la zona o país, esto varía grandamente depende del país.

Answer (score 3):

Yes.

In English, the word "film" may mean a thin layer covering a surface (such as "a film or dust") or movie.

Similarly, in Spanish, the word "pelicula" may mean a thin layer covering a surface (as in "una película de polvo") or movie.

Comment: +1 `In English, the word "film" may mean a thin layer covering a surface (such as "a film or dust") or movie.`  I found it weird no one else mentioned it. The English language itself uses the [same word](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Film_(disambiguation)) to convey both meanings.

Comment: @Ramon Melo Exactly. The reason movies are called films is because they are made by a light coat (a film) of silver emulsions on celluloid.

Answer (score 2):

The Spanish word '*película*' means any thin coating or thin layer.

So, as in English a celluloid film is the transparent layer used to record a movie (in its original form), in Spanish the word '*película*' was used for "movie" by metonymy from "film".

But the original meaning "film" is in perfect usage, like in this '*película de polvo*'. See also '*película de jabón*'.

Answer (score -1):

I checked three online translating sites, and it seems babylon.com could be the most useful:

http://www.translate.com/ says "movie"

bing translator gives "feminine film; movie; ..."

http://translation.babylon.com/spanish/to-english/pelicula/ says:
film, thin coating, thin layer; membrane; thin flexible material coated with light sensitive emulsion (Photography); motion picture, movie